# Convex order and an integral inequality over quantile functions

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be random variables in $L^1$. We will write $X \preceq_c Y$ if for all convex functions $u$ on $\mathbb{R}$

$$ \mathbb{E} [u(X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[u(Y)].$$

Now let $q_X$ and $q_Y$ be the (left-continuous) quantile functions of $X$ and $Y$.

How to prove that

$$ \int_0^t q_X(s) d s \geq \int_0^t q_Y(s) ds$$

for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$ given $X \preceq_c Y$?

The case $t=0$ is trivial. For $t=1$ note that if $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, then $q_X (U)$ is distributed as $X$. Thus,

$$\int_0^1 q_X (s) ds = \mathbb{E}[q_X(U)] = \mathbb{E} [X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^1 q_Y (s) ds $$

since $x \mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto -x$ are both convex.

But I don't see how this can be generalized to prove the case where $t$ is not $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [source for a direct proof](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02934633). Thanks to the two answers for telling me where to look.

Comment: Nice to see you find something that worked. The source you cite is older, but also employs essentially the same argument found in Brooks and Du. I suppose B&D were unable to find your source when they tried to prove their lemma.

Comment: This might make a good Comment (or edit) on your original Question, but it does not serve as a useful Answer in its present form.  While links can be helpful, without a summary of the information given there they are flagged as "link-only" Answers.  See [Provide context for links](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 3):

It is relatively well-known that $X \preceq_c Y$ if and only if $Y$ is a mean-preserving spread of $X$. (If this is not something you already know, I imagine it might be found in the links in [kimchi lover's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2912648/388944). Otherwise, it's probably in [Shaked and Shanthikumar](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387329154).)

The result you are looking for is stated as lemma $1$ of [Brooks and Du (2018)](http://www.benjaminbrooks.net/downloads/brooksdu_maxmin.pdf). The proof is in their appendix.

Apologies for the brief answer. I don't have time to write a detailed one at the moment, and I thought you'd rather a brief one sooner rather than a detailed one (possibly much) later. I'll try to find the time to develop this into a full answer later on.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to prove something like Theorem 5 in David Blackwell's paper [Comparison of Experiments](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bsmsp/1200500222) .  Blackwell's functions $F_M$ and $F_m$ are, I think, the inverse functions of your $q_X$ and $q_Y$ (or maybe vice versa; the notations make my head spin).  In general, your hypothesis $Eu(X)\le Eu(Y)$ for all convex $u$ is pretty strong, and has well-known necessary and sufficient equivalents, as in the famous [paper of Cartier, et al](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1964__92__435_0.pdf).  The exposition in Le Cam's [Comparison of Experiments - A short review](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215453569) (see esp. the bottom of page 130) might serve as a roadmap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping to find a direct proof somewhere. There is also a (convoluted) proof in Föllmer&Schieds "Stochastic Finance" (Chapter 2). Seems like one has to dissect that to arrive at a direct argument.